# what's paravirtualization?

Tags: virtualization

Can anyone help to explain the word `paravirtualization` in simple English? I have some difficulty in understanding it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is the right place for this kind of question, but [paravirtualization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paravirtualization) is a form of virtualization in which the guest runs a modified kernel - that is, a kernel that is aware of the fact that it's running virtualized and uses some kind of specialized API to interact with the host. This allows for optimization and simplification of certain costly operations, like I/O.

The most widely used virtualization system that uses paravirtualization (exclusively in its beginning, optionally now) is probably [Xen](http://www.xen.org/), but other systems sometimes use paravirtualized drivers.